# swift, iOS App froze when entering the chat view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hello guys I am now currently working on an chat app using collectionViewController. My chat app works great, however I want to add the date on the top of each collection cell. So I use collection reusableView as section header to display the date. I created a xib file for reusable view which contains a label. MessageArray is dictionary I used to fetch all the data, since I want to display time for every collection view cell, so I return messageArray.count for the number of section. And I also register the view in the viewDidLoad so all the set ups are right. But I am having the issue whenever I open the chatlog, the app froze and xcode did not tell me where the problem occurred or what is the problem. Can anyone help me out pls, thank you.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "timeStampId", for: indexPath) as! timeStampCollectionReusableView

    let timeInSeconds = messageArray[indexPath.item].timeStamp!
    let timeInSecondsDouble = Double(timeInSeconds)
    let timeStampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInSecondsDouble)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    view.timeStamp.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timeStampDate as Date)
    //view.timeStamp.text = "hello world"
    return view
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame.size.width)!, height: 40)
    return size
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //return messageArray.count
    return messageArray.count
}
```

Comment: You set up `timeStampDate` as `NSDate` but then you cast it to `Date`. In Swift, don’t use `NSDate`. Try it as a `Date` type and don’t cast it to see if that helps.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint at the beginning of the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)` method and go throw it step by step. You will find which line of code causes an app freezing.